# How to add friend programmatically?

Tags: google-api, youtube-data-api, google-authentication

I am adding friends on YouTube so that I can easily share videos with them as well chatting about the video.
I am currently sending the "Invite" link, and my friends have to use the link to add me.

Is there any YouTube Data API that allows me to achieve this programmatically? (Assuming I have obtained the grant of the relevant google oauth2 scope)

- I have looked through YouTube Developer Data APIs
  https://developers.google.com/youtube/
- I have also examined the list of all google oauth scopeshttps://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes

I expect some documentation about the related google scope as well API

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not how the YouTube API works. The YouTube api is more designed for you to manage your YouTube channel upload videos and see comments.

The YouTube api is not designed around managing a users YouTube account. There is now way to add friends directly though the API.